# Navbar different screen size

Tags: html, css

I want my navbar to be horizontal on desktop and vertical on mobile.
But it doesn't work with my code. It is horizontal on desktop and mobile.

What's the issue with my code?

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

.

```
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  display: none;
  ul.topnav li.right, 
  ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `flexbox` and `float` and `float` **does not work in flexbox**. You'd have to change the `flex-direction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this media for your example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ViDiX fine! Vote up, bro